# What is the grammatical logic and meaning of "going to" in the sentence "we are going to need them"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Even though I am a native English speaker, I am old and have forgotten my English grammar lessons. Need a little help to understand why I would write a sentence that way using the words going to even though I've always done it that way.

Comment: Would you please give some more detailed context?

Comment: Not sure I can. The sentence I used in my initial posting was just made up to model the use of "going to" to say something and illustrates how I normally speak or write. BTW I am from the deep South if that means anything to you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a form of the future tense in English.
[ThoughtCo.com: "expressing future tense with 'will' and 'going to'](https://www.thoughtco.com/guide-to-future-1211192)

As to why "going to" *is* used as future tense in English, I'm going to pass on that one. Maybe someone else will chime in.

Comment: I'll chime in and say it's pretty much a universal metaphoric feature of (all?) natural languages that we're continuously "traveling" from the Present to the Future - so whereas we ***came from*** the Past, we're ***going to*** the Future.

Comment: I can add that French futur proche (je vais + infinitive) and Spanish futuro próximo (voy a +infinitive) explicitly use the same metaphor, with a verb meaning "to go".